# Missing icons in opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: html, css, opencart, font-awesome, opencart2.x

I have opencart 2.0.1.1 version and it was working fine. Suddenly I found that the icons like contact us, wish list, search were missing. I tried to find the icons in images folder but couldn't find it out.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

1. The first image is the header image where the contact us and other icons are missing.
2. In the second image the search icon and the cart icon in add to cart button is missing
3. The third image is the search result and the home icon is missing and the arrow is misplaced.

Even the arrow in the slide bar is missing.

Should I upload the images again. If I should upload where should I do that.

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug missing images is take a look in your browser's web inspector as the page loads and you should be able to see which assets are missing and where they should be located.

The Firebug extension for Firefox is extremely helpful for this and many other basic client side debugging tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are missing the "font awesome" font.

Please check your folder: OPENCART ROOT->catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/fonts

And check if you have 5 files named:

- FontAwesome.otf
- fontawesome-webfont.eot
- fontawesome-webfont.svg
- fontawesome-webfont.ttf
- fontawesome-webfont.woff

If not, download opencart again and copy over those files.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing FontAwesome issue in open cart

```
   // HTTP
    define(‘HTTP_SERVER’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com‘);

    // HTTPS
    define(‘HTTPS_SERVER’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com‘);

    config.php – OpenCart admin folder
    // HTTP
    define(‘HTTP_SERVER’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com/admin/‘);
    define(‘HTTP_CATALOG’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com/‘);

    // HTTPS
    define(‘HTTPS_SERVER’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com/admin/‘);
    define(‘HTTPS_CATALOG’, ‘https://www.blazingcoders.com/‘);
```

Detail Explanation is given in the below article 
https://www.blazingcoders.com/how-to-fix-opencart-missing-icons-problem